# Serializing foreign keys as list in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize the data

```
class Main(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class ForeignKey(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main,on_related='foreign_key')
```

I want to get the result like

```
{'title':'hello', 'foreign_key':'['foreign_key1','foreign_key2','foreign_key3']'
```

I first thought I could make it work in the 'views.py', but some documents told me that there is a thing like 'listField' in serializer, which has too little examples..

What would be the way here?

Answer (score 3):

Write your serializer as ,

```
#serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class ForeignKeySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ForeignKey
        fields = '__all__'


class MainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foreign_key = ForeignKeySerializer(source='foreignkey_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Main
        fields = ("title", "foreign_key")
```

then write your views as,

```
#views.py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view()
def sample_view(request):
    queryset = Main.objects.all()
    serializer = MainSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

---

### References

1. [DRF-Serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)
2. [DRF-views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/)